# What's Up With the Dancing Shadows?

Tags: howls-moving-castle

In Howl's Moving Castle, Madame Soloman shows Sophie the "real Howl." When this happens, they're standing on the universe while these little shadows start to sing and dance. What does this have to do with the "real Howl?"